# MVC View not refreshed after menu click (angularjs is being used)

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an MVC site with some of the pages using angular using the angular silo pattern.

If I navigate to a non angular page routing works fine taking me to the controller and then then view. However once on that page if I click on the same menu item again I am not routed to the controller method as before, nothing happens.

I don't know if this is default behaviour and I haven't noticed, a caching issue, or if using angular has changed something.

Has anyone had this issue, and how do you get the second click of the menu to route to the controller

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
  return View();
}

<li>
<a href="/Monitoring/Dashboard" id="MonitoringSubmenu" target="">Monitoring</a>
</li>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: what code do you want (controller, layout view, view, route config) I would of thought the question raised wouldn't require code??

Comment: I want to know what is happening when you click on the menu item. so the code for menu would help I guess

Comment: There's nothing special about it dude, but it's added

Comment: try turning off caching the controller: `$stateProvider.state('stateName', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/url',
   templateUrl : 'template.html'
})`

Comment: I believe I might be confusing the post by mentioning angular. The page in question is not an angular view, it is just an MVC controller with a Razor view...No angular. I mentioned angular because I thought it might of effected the MVC routing when installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jahongir Rahmonov's answer was not correct as the page is NOT an angular page, however calling a javascript function which calls the controller did fix the problem, so many thanks Below is the code

```
<a onclick="changeRouteToDashboard()" href="" id="MonitoringSubmenu" target="">Monitoring</a>

function changeRouteToDashboard(){
    window.location.href = "/Monitoring/Dashboard"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the default behavior of angular.

There is a workaround this, however. You can use `ng-click` to change the route and ensure that a controller method is called every time, even if you are on that same page:

```
 <a ng-click="changeRouteToDashboard()" id="MonitoringSubmenu" target="">Monitoring</a>
```

and in your controller:

```
function changeRouteToDashboard(){
    $location.path('/Monitoring/Dashboard')
}
```